# Custom Dialog with do not show this again

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am getting problem with custom dialog, i created custom dialog and it works properly but im having confusion about not showing it again if user click on button. Like there is a button named rating when ever user click on that button then custom dialog will never open again. So if anyone knows how to do it then please help me

**This is my code**

```
   final Dialog dialogrul = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialogrul.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = dialogrul.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialogrul.setContentView(R.layout.exitlayout);
    Button rating = dialogrul.findViewById(R.id.ratingok);
    Button dialogok = dialogrul.findViewById(R.id.exityes);
    final Button dialognotok = dialogrul.findViewById(R.id.exitno);

    dialogrul.setCancelable(true);
    dialogrul.show();
    dialogok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.onSuperBackPressed();
            finish();

        }
    });
    rating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent j = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            j.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?"));
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
    dialognotok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogrul.cancel();

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to write to a file to store a variable wich says if he clicked on the button

This is to read the file:

```
private String readFromFile(Context context) {

        String ret = "";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("yourfilename.txt");

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { } catch (IOException e) { }

        return ret;
    }
```

and this is to write to the file:

```
private void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
        String x=readFromFile(this);
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("yourfilename.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }
```